# How to factory reset an EPSON Stylus Photo 1290 printer?

Tags: inkjet-printer

How do I do **factory reset** on an EPSON Stylus Photo 1290 printer?

The printer is refusing to work. It seems to be in some error state. I've tried re-installing drivers etc, but the printer itself seems to run some diagnostic routine when I switch it on, but will not do anything else. It will not move the carousel ready for me to change the printer cartridge when I press ink change button.

Is there some sequence of button presses on the printer to do a factory reset? The printer has three buttons on the front, plus a yellow button when the hood is open (as shown in this photo)

[image]

Comment: Did you try to unplug power and hold power button for cca 30s?

Comment: [This](http://www.s-manuals.com/printer/epson_sp1290) should help, look for Troubleshooting :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how reliable [this website](http://www.bismut.net/manual-reset-for-epson-stylus-color-printer/) is, but try the following:

> EPSON Stylus Photo 890, 1280, 1290
>
> 1. [Press] and [hold] Maintenance and Roll Paper buttons, press POWER button, You will see blinking Power led.
> 2. Release all buttons.
> 3. In 2-3 seconds time the led will blink. Press and hold for 10-12 seconds the Roll Paper button, until all leds blink.
>
> [Grammar fixes in article are mine]

Answer (score 1):

According to [the Service Manual](http://www.s-manuals.com/manuals/printer/epson/epson_stylus_photo_890,1280,1290_service_manual.pdf.zip), that's sounds like a "Fatal error", meaning the printer needs physical servicing (for testing and/or replacing of internal parts).

In that manual, check section 3.1.1.7 for a list of "Fatal Error" symptoms to see exactly which one matches what you are experiencing.

Unless you have the know how and replacement parts, it's probably time to take it in for repair, or replace it.